# promise.all doesnt seem to wait for all promises to resolve

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, es6-promise

Hey I get that this may be answered somewhere else but I can't find one that fits my needs. This code:

```
async function makeCharts(coin){
  let results = await Promise.all([getDailyData(coin), getCurrentData(coin)])
  makeCurrentLineChart(coin, results[1])
  makeHighLowLineChart(coin, results[0])
}
```

does not seem to wait for the array of results to be resolved. The two chart methods sometimes are passes no data, sometimes it works perfectly.

These are the async functions:

```
async function getDailyData(coin){
  let response = {}
  try{
    response = await axios.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=DIGITAL_CURRENCY_DAILY&symbol='+ coin +'&market=USD&apikey=' + APIKEY)
  }catch(err){
    response = err
  }
  let obj = { labels: [], highdata: [], lowdata: [] }
  const data = response.data['Time Series (Digital Currency Daily)']
  let i = 0
  for(let key in data){
    if(i == 21) break; 
    i = i+1
    obj.labels.push(key)
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      obj.highdata.push(parseFloat(data[key]['2a. high (USD)']))
      obj.lowdata.push(parseFloat(data[key]['3a. low (USD)']))
    }
  }
  return obj
}

async function getCurrentData(coin){
  let response = {}
  try{
    response = await axios.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=DIGITAL_CURRENCY_INTRADAY&symbol='+ coin +'&market=USD&apikey=' + APIKEY)
  }catch(err){
    response = err
  }
  let obj = { labels: [], currentdata: [] }
  const data = response.data['Time Series (Digital Currency Intraday)']
  let i = 0
  for(let key in data){
    if(i == 100) break; 
    i = i+1
    obj.labels.push(key.split(' ')[1])
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      obj.currentdata.push(parseFloat(data[key]['1a. price (USD)']))
    }
  }
  return obj
}
```

I have looked at Daniel Shiffman's promise video and this seems to match the logic there:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01RTj1MWec0&t=57s

I also looked here and the makeCharts function matches the syntax there, just above the Summary section:

https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: That code should work. We're going to need a concrete example. My guess is that the API your using has a hit limit and your going over so it returns a 500 or something. But that's a pure guess

Comment: I agree with Liam, the code looks correct

Comment: Okay that's reassuring. Will probably make an update soon. Emailed the endpoint's support team.

Comment: `Promise.all()` resolves immediately if any of the Promises reject, which means not all Promises will have, necessarily, completed when `Promise.all()` resolves as a reject. You can program around this, by basically calling `Promise.all()` again w/o the rejected Promises. However, your use of `Promise.all()` appears to be useless. Neither function which you are calling returns a Promise. They are both made fully synchronous by `await`ing the `axios.get()`, which means that the `axios.get()` calls are made completely serially, not in parallel (i.e. the `Promise.all()` is, at best, useless).

Comment: In addition, you have put the `await axios.get()` in a `try`/`catch` block and assigned the rejection value to `response`, instead of more reasonably/explicitly handling a rejection. I haven't looked at the documentation for `axios.get()`, but it probably doesn't reject with an Object that has a `data` property, which means that your assumption (`const data = ...`) that `response.data` is an Object will probably throw an error when the `axios.get()` rejects.